# Assessing match of least cost path with realized path using

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, least-cost

I have a client who is using least cost path analysis to find paths between locations(brown points).  He also has the realized, mapped paths between the same points.
For instance, say the black lines are the LCPs and the white lines are the realized paths.  (They are actually two different versions of realized paths but I don't think that matters here).

[image]

**He would like to find a way to assess the accuracy of the LCP-predicted paths and find out how well they match the realized paths. Is there a standard way to do this?**

The best idea I came up with is to compute the Hausdorff Distance between the paths.  Would we compute a single distance between the entire network? Or I also thought we could break the problem into the path between all pairs of points.

Below we have a pair of (starred) points, the distance as the crow flies (red), the shortest distance along the black path (blue), the shortest distance along the white path (green).

Would we compute the Hausdorff distance between the blue and green paths, declare this the "error" for the LCP model for those pair of points, and then calculate this for all pairs of points?

[image]

Does ArcMap have a method for Hausdorff Distance?

I see that PostGIS has [ST_HausdorffDistance()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_HausdorffDistance.html).

Comment: Scipy comes with ArcGis and it has this function. However it works on a pairs of vertices. More accurate and easier is converting pair of lines into polygons. Total of their areas divided by average of 2 lengths is very robust measure of mismatch